# Dll missing from bin for website project

Tags: asp.net, reference, bin

I have a solution , for that I am referencing to Newstonsoft Dll(reference location is a separate reference folder in side the website). Each time I delete the Bin folder & Re-build it, Newstonsoft Dll is not generating .

Tried by adding from NuGet Manager even, same case for both. Ultimately solution file is not taking the reference. can you please suggest any good way to resolve this?

N.B-->This is a Website

Comment: That's applicable for the web project, Not for Website. It's legacy one so even can't modify .

Comment: Okay, and what is this *N.B-->This is a Website*

Comment: it's the major point, I.e. the question related to website :)

Comment: Why do you delete the Bin folder every time? When (re)building the project the files in the Bin will be overwritten.

Comment: Yes right, I am giving the scenario, because if the reference will be overridden how come we can know which dll is missing. This issue arrived as we are using VSO, where this type of scenarios will raise on each build, as the Agent pool is different.